# Add points at a certain X values in R

Tags: r, plot

How can I add points at a certain x value? 
For example I have the following data:

```
c(1,2,3)
c(5,6,7)
```

Now, I want the following plot: 
[image]

I.e., I want to add points (5,6,7), at X values (6,7,8)

The following code does not help:

```
plot(c(1,2,3),xlim=c(1,8),ylim=c(1,10))
points(c(5,6,7))
```

What should be done?

Comment: `points(c(6,7, 8), c(5, 6, 7))` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a one-liner you can achieve the plotting of all six coordinates like this:

```
plot(c(1,2,3,6,7,8),c(1,2,3,5,6,7),xlim=c(1,8),ylim=c(1,10),xlab="x index", ylab="y values")
```

Moreover, you can add additional points to your plot with the `points` function, see the [official R documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/points.html) for reference. 
With `points` function the

> coordinates can be passed in a plotting structure (a list with x and y components), a two-column matrix, a time series, ....

This way, the example becomes:

```
plot(c(1,2,3),xlim=c(1,8),ylim=c(1,10),xlab="x index", ylab="y values")
points(c(6,7,8),c(5,6,7))
```

Comment: For a quick web-based check, use: http://rextester.com/l/R_online_compiler